# Count the number of elements in sets A&B, A&~B, ~A&B

Tags: sql, count, full-outer-join

Table A is a list of IDs.

```
ID
---
1
5
9
...
```

Table B has IDs and another Y/N value.

```
ID   Value
----------
1      0
2      1
3      0
...
```

I'd the count of Value for IDs that are:
i) both in tables A & B,
ii) in A but not B,
iii) in B but A.

One way is to use union:

```
SELECT Value, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB USING (id) GROUP BY Value
UNION 
SELECT Value, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tableA RIGHT JOIN tableB USING (id) WHERE tableA.id IS NULL GROUP BY Value
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: and in cases ii and iv there will be only NULL in B.Value

Comment: please share the output you expect.  using a UNION between these queries is almost certainly wrong

Comment: Should add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want ids from both tables, which reads like a `full join` (if your database, which you did not tag, does support it). We can then compute the counts with conditional expressions.

```
select 
    sum(case when t1.id is not null and t2.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) cnt_in_both_tables,
    sum(case when t1.id is not null and t2.id is     null then 1 else 0 end) cnt_in_t1_only,
    sum(case when t1.id is     null and t2.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) cnt_in_t2_only
from mytable1 t1
full join mytable2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

This assumes that ids are unique in both table, as shown in your sample data - otherwise we would need to deduplicate both datasets first.

In databases that do not support full joins, we would likely emulate it with `union` and subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

RDBMS not indicated and I use Access which does not support FULL OUTER JOIN. Consider:

```
SELECT "InBoth" AS Cat, B.ID, Count(*) AS Cnt FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID GROUP BY "Both", B.ID
UNION SELECT "InAnotB", A.ID, Count(*) FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID WHERE (((B.ID) Is Null)) GROUP BY "InAnotB", A.ID
UNION SELECT "InBnotA", B.ID, Count(*) FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON B.ID = A.ID WHERE (((A.ID) Is Null)) GROUP BY "InBnotA", B.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The different sets (A&B, A&~B, ~A&B) represent different ways you can join your tables.

I am assuming the column *ID* is the primary key in table A as well as in table B, if not you need to add a DISTINCT inside the count, e.g. COUNT(DISTINCT A.id).

**A&B** = inner join table A and B on column ID -> returns only rows with IDs that exist in both tables

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
```

**A&~B** = A left join B on column ID and filter on B.id is null -> keeps all values in table A, joins table B onto table A and keeps only the rows where it could not find a matching value in B

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

**~A&B** = A right join B on column ID and filter on A.id is null -> keeps all values in table B, joins table A onto table B and keeps only the rows where it could not find a matching value in A

```
SELECT COUNT(B.id)
FROM A
RIGHT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.id IS NULL
```

Alternatively, you can use a left join for **~A&B**, just make sure your tables are on the correct side of the join depending on the intended outcome and that you filter on the correct column.

```
SELECT COUNT(B.id)
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON B.id = A.id
WHERE A.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the approach of the previous answer, but with a more compact solution (assuming that the ID field is mandatory and unique in both tables):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.ID = B.ID THEN 1 END) AS "A and B",
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.ID is null THEN 1 END) AS "A but not B",
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.ID is null THEN 1 END) AS "B but not A" 
FROM tableA A FULL OUTER JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.id
```

Comment: @SiddharthaMukherjee Please don't abuse code format for non-code. (And there isn't any reason to emphasize that phrase. And the phrase is actually being de-emphasized in the first place by being put in parentheses.) (And some code indented by only an extra 4 characters is not much of an improvement. But I kept that change of yours anyway.)